# Convert a geodataframe into an OSMNX graph?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx

I have a road network shapefile with a few different attributes. I want to study the network orientation by filtering shapefile based on these attributes. I can do the filtering in geopandas but didnt find any way to convert those dataframes into osmnx graphs. Currently I need to save the filtered geodataframe as a shapefile, load it in JOSM and then save it as an .osm file to get it into osmnx. Seems like there must be a more direct approach.

Comment: Did you read the documentation and usage examples? They explain how to convert GeoDataFrames to a graph https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs

Comment: Thanks that is very helpfull. I missed this function. A quick follow up I am filtering the graph edges using an attribute but not the nodes. But putting in the original node dataframe and the filtered edges dataframe seems to work with osmnx.utils_graph.graph_from_gdf in generating a new graph. But i am not sure if this is the correct way to do this.